# The flutter app using 'webview_flutter' or 'flutter_inappbrowser' is stuck when I slide right back to the previous page

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

There are two pages that contains webview, and their routing order is A to B.
while sliding right slowly at the B page to return A, the app is stuck in the middle-state with A and B display half of each.

I found the following rules:
1. Both A and B must contain the webview;
2. The webview in A can be any height, even 0;
3. The problem occurs only when the sliding finger is within the scope of the webview of B.

The webview lib is `flutter_inappbrowser: ^0.6.0`, and the problem can occur in the simplest way to use.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

there is a new version of the plugin published which will help you.

use flutter_inappbrowser: ^1.1.1

Comment: Sorry, the new version also has the problem.

Comment: I also used flutter_inappwebview: ^2.1.0 but still not working. Any solutions? thanks